# How to redirect request to another namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, api, routes

What's the best way to forward all unhandled requests within a namespace to another namespace, while preserving the format of the original request?

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    ...
  end

  namespace :v2 do
    ...
  end

  # works but doesn't respect original request format (json, xml, etc.)
  match '*route' => redirect("/api/v2/%{route}")
end
```

The above will allow the API consumer to choose between the latest version of the API or a specific one.

Props if you can show how to do this without the visible redirect.